# CodeIgniter URL_TITLE UTF8 Characters?

Tags: codeigniter, url

I have problem with codeigniter something like this i have string this like

```
$string="Mučnina – problem u vožnji!";
```

When i do something like this

```
$url_title = url_title($string, '_', TRUE);
```

I got this

```
$string="munina_problem_u_vonji";
```

Big difference?

How to modified url_title parameters?

Comment: How do you want it modified? Do you want č to become "c"?

Comment: Yes č to c, ž to z and all othert UTF8-unicode-ci

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what i done :

**1.** go to **application/config/foreign_chars.php**

**2.** added

```
'/š/' => 's', 
'/đ/' => 'd', 
'/č/' => 'c', 
'/ć/' => 'c', 
'/ž/' => 'z', 
'/Š/' => 'S', 
'/Đ/' => 'D', 
'/Č/' => 'C', 
'/Ć/' => 'C', 
'/Ž/' => 'Z',
```

**3.** Just call

```
$clean=convert_accented_characters($string);
 $url_title = url_title($clean, '_', TRUE);
```

Answer (score 3):

The built-in url title function won't work in itself for you since it's just replaces everyting matches `[^a-z0-9 _-]` with empty string.

Try running [`convert_accented_characters()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/text_helper.html) first on your input, that function takes it's replacements from the `config/foreign_chars.php` file, so something like this:

```
url_title(convert_accented_characters($string), '_', TRUE);
```

Comment: Fixed by little of your help, this is what i done : 
1. go to application/config/foreign_chars.php
2. added
        `'/š/' => 's',`
 `'/đ/' => 'd',`
 `'/č/' => 'c',`
 `'/ć/' => 'c',`
 `'/ž/' => 'z',`
 `'/Š/' => 'S',`
 `'/Đ/' => 'D',`
 `'/Č/' => 'C',`
 `'/Ć/' => 'C',`
 `'/Ž/' => 'Z',`
3. Added

`$clean=convert_accented_characters($string);`

4.Just call

`$url_title = url_title($clean, '_', TRUE);`

And got all good and nice, txanks mate